# ImageContext returns image distorted

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimage

I'm trying to make corners of the image round but the image from ImageContext is distorted.

This is the steps I am taking:

```
- (UIImage *)decodeBase64ToImage:(NSString *)strEncodedData
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strEncodedData];
    NSData* data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    UIImage* croppedImage = [self makeRoundedImage:image];
    return croppedImage;
}

- (UIImage *)makeRoundedImage:(UIImage *) image
{

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(frame.size);
    //[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height) cornerRadius:10.0] addClip];
    [image drawInRect:frame];

    // Get the image
    UIImage *croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    // Lets forget about that we were drawing
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return croppedImage;
}
```

Comment: I think no need make corners of the UIImage.  You need to make corners of the UIImageView.

Comment: @YogendraGirase I can't use UIImageView, I need to use it in a framework that works only with UIImage.

Comment: You can check below my answer.It may be helpful for you

Comment: @YogendraGirase seems to work in the UIImageView, both answers, I think there is something wrong in the framework that I use after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can check this method**

```
-(UIImage *)roundedImage:(UIImage *) roundImage 
                      radius: (float) radius;
{
  CALayer *imageLayer = [CALayer layer];
  imageLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, roundImage.size.width, roundImage.size.height);
  imageLayer.contents = (id) roundImage.CGImage;

  imageLayer.masksToBounds = YES;
  imageLayer.cornerRadius = radius;

  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(roundImage.size);
  [imageLayer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
  UIImage *finalRoundedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  return finalRoundedImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This.**

```
-(UIImage *)imageWithRoundedCorner:(float)cornerRadius Image:(UIImage *)realImage
{
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:realImage];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.bounds.size, NO, 1.0);
    [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:imageView.bounds cornerRadius:cornerRadius] addClip];
    [realImage drawInRect:imageView.bounds];
    imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return imageView.image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this., it will solve problem of image distortion..

```
- (UIImage *)makeRoundedImage:(UIImage *) image
{

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(frame.size, NO, 0);
    //[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height) cornerRadius:10.0] addClip];
    [image drawInRect:frame];

    // Get the image
    UIImage *croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    // Lets forget about that we were drawing
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return croppedImage;
}
```

Comment: I found the issue, my other framework was not accepting UIImage directly from ImageContext, so I had to convert it to PNG Representation and then it worked, but thanks!